# Stop villagers from making bread

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've created a villager farm with the purpose of creating wheat/seeds. But I noticed that the villager started crafting bread, instead of throwing wheat/seeds at my other villager.

Is there a way to stop this villager from creating bread and only farm wheat and seeds?

Comment: I think it you give them a lot of bread, they won't make new bread, but I'm not sure. What kind of villager can do you have?

Comment: @Fabian I have a leatherworker as 'receiver' and a fisher man as the farmer

Comment: Also, I tried filling up his inventory with bread, but it seems like it's already full with seeds or wheat

Comment: Then I don't know a way.

Comment: Yes. Just fill up their inventory. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7fnatRPiDl4

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph I think I'm going to build one of those. I followed unarybit's design, but I guess that won't work for wheat.

Comment: @AnonymousPerson Just grab the world download and replace whatever crop is in the example world with wheat using /fill command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Villagers who pick up wheat, won't share it with other villagers. They will instead bake bread and share 50% of the bread they have (if it's in large quantities) with others who need food. As far as I am informed making a wheat farm is impossible if you want to use villagers, due to the reason mentioned above.

You can, however, make potato or carrot farms with farmer villagers (the ones with brown coats and no other collars), but make sure they have an empty inventory - when new villagers are born after mating they have empty inventory until someone throws something at them. If your villager is planting stuff you don't want him to just walk around with him and destroy his seeds, you will then pick them up and he is gonna use up all of his supplies for planting.

After that, you can throw him the types of seeds you need him to plant for the farm. Keep in mind that farmers won't pickup or plant sugarcanes.

My advice would be, if you need the bread for your own consumption, to just instead make a potato farm.

Comment: I have built the other farms too, but I just want the wheat for breeding cows/sheep and trading with farming villagers for emeralds. I have a cow cooker/farm for my food, so I'm good on that part.

Comment: He is just gonna plant more wheat and share bread. Look up around the internet but I don't think its possible to have an automated farm for raw wheat.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a wheat farm using villagers. I haven't seen anything like it yet on YouTube or anything. It's quite simple though. You just have to let the villager out of a locked house for a day. Give him some seeds and let him plant. Then when he goes to bed lock the door (iron door) and keep him inside for 2 days to let the wheat grow. Then have water break and collect the items in a chest but give the seeds back to the villager and repeat the process.

Answer (score 0):

Because  seeds and villagers interact. You need to do fill your farmer's entire inventory with seeds so they can't make bread or pick up wheat, and use hopper minecarts under the land to pick up the wheat instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use water flow from dispensers with a redstone system and hoppers with chests at the other end to reap the wheat before the farmer can clear the field then throw him seeds from time to time to keep his inventory full of seeds, he will reap and replant on his own but any wheat turns into bread and the water will wash away some of the seeds that would've normally refilled his inv... so topping off his seed stores is advised

Answer (score 0):

LogicalGeekBoy has a really good tutorial on how to create a wheat farm that prevents Villagers from collecting wheat and turning it into bread here:

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.